# What is Ba'al's human persona name?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the episode *[Ex Deus Machina](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ex_Deus_Machina)*, Ba'al impersonates a CEO of a defense contractor. He even gives a press conference. What was Ba'al's human name he told everyone? I pretty sure he didn't introduce himself as

> "*The System Lord, Ba'al*".

[image: Ba'al as a CEO]

Comment: We don't see it on screen, nor does it appear in the show script. I'm assuming it was something like '*John Bahal*', '*Mark Ball*' or '*Adam Barl*'

Comment: @Valorum I always assumed his first name was [Bachi](https://themeaningofthename.com/bachi/).

Comment: Base. Base Ba'al.

Comment: It's not 100% clear from the image, but I think he's standing in front of a poster for Hammel Technologies. If we assume that this is his company, and that Ba'al considers himself witty, his name may well be "Mark Hammel" as a homonym for Mark Hamill pointing to his space based origin.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [transcript of the episode](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/9.07_%22Ex_Deus_Machina%22_Transcript), the human name he's using is never given through the episode.

Since he had several clones working on Earth at the time, it's likely that he was using several human names to conduct his business.